# A field in sqlite database is phone numbers. Some start with 0 and rest start with +91. I want to replace the number which start with 0 with +91

Tags: android, sqlite, replace

I have a field in Sqlite database which are phone numbers. Some start with `0XXXXXXX` and others start with `+91XXXXXXX`.

I want to replace the phone number which start with 0 with +91. When I use the replace function of sqlite it also replaces any other 0 in the phone number with +91.

For example a number is `0987654321`. On using replace function of sqlite the field becomes `+91987654321`

but if the number is `09876054320` then using replace converts it to `+919876+915432+91` which I don't want. I should be able to make the output as `+919876054320`

Comment: How you are replacing it?

Comment: Can you post the query?

Comment: You'd better store the numbers as **INTEGER** and then add `"+91"` only in the UI.

Comment: replace(phoneNumber, '0', '+91')

Comment: frank the problem is that i have 1000's of rows already which either start with 0 or +91

Answer (score 0):

To snip off only the first character, use the [substr() function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr):

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET PhoneNumber = '+91' || substr(PhoneNumber, 2)
WHERE PhoneNumber LIKE '0%';
```